# Laravel and Vue: How to decrease bundle size when adding in Vuetify?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vue with an existing Laravel setup.  When I run `npm run production`, the bundle size is fairly large at 1.1MB.  There are only a few components and I believe it is Vuetify that is taking up the size.
I have used Vue with Laravel in the past and had far more components than this and the bundle was only 300KB so I think the culprit must be Vuetify.
Is there anyway to further reduce this though without getting rid of Vuetify?  I copied my `webpack.mix.js` file as well.  Are there optimizations here that I am missing out on that could reduce the bundle size?

**main.js**

```
window.axios = require('axios');
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import store from './store/store';


import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import ReferralSetup from './components/admin/ReferralSetup';
import ReferralStats from './components/admin/ReferralStats';
import ReferralInstructional from './components/admin/ReferralInstructional';
import BoxSection from './components/admin/BoxSection';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

Vue.component('referral-setup', ReferralSetup);
Vue.component('referral-stats', ReferralStats);
Vue.component('referral-instructional', ReferralInstructional);
Vue.component('box-section', BoxSection);
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix             = require('laravel-mix');
let VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for your application, as well as bundling up your JS files.
 |
 */

mix .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'dist/js')


mix.options({
  extractVueStyles: false, // Extract .vue component styling to file, rather than inline.
  purifyCss: true // Remove unused CSS selectors.
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered extracting your vendor files to a separate file?  This would allow you to set long cache times on vendor files and have smaller downloads on application updates.

**Vendor Extraction**
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#vendor-extraction

**webpack.mix.js**

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['vue','vuetify','...'])
```

**layout.blade.php**

```php
...

<script src="/js/manifest.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

**Bundle Analyzer**
You might check out the [Laravel Mix Bundle Analyzer](https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/bundle-analyzer) if you really want to see where your issues are.

**Lodash**
Also, you might look into only loading the lodash modules you need, since it has historically been included in Laravel's bootstrap.js file.

```js
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

window._ = { debounce };
```

Comment: ah extracting vendor files, that's great.... going to apply this right now, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

We are using Vuetify 1.5.x

`import Vuetify from 'vuetify';`

which points to ~/node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js (which is 1.1MB)

So instead I opted for

`import Vuetify from 'vuetify.min.js';`

that points to ~/node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js (size 334Kb)

It pretty much helped me reducing the bundle size.